# Invalid parse of ternary expression VC2008?

Tags: c, visual-studio, ternary-operator

The following code gives me a compiler warning

```
warning C4133: ':' : incompatible types - from 'YTYPE *' to 'XTYPE *'
```

however, the expession seems OK to me. Any ideas?

```
struct XTYPE {
    int x;
    long y;
};
struct YTYPE {
    long y;
    int x;
};

extern void *getSomething(void);

void Test(void)
{
    int b= 0;
    struct XTYPE *pX;
    struct YTYPE *pY;

    void * (*pfFoo)(void);

    pfFoo= getSomething;

    if (b ? (pX= (*pfFoo)())       // error
          : (pY= (*pfFoo)()) )
    {
        ;
    }
    if (b ? ((pX= (*pfFoo)())!=0)  // no error
          : ((pY= (*pfFoo)())!=0) )
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a constraint violation, simply put. To begin with, the type of an assignment expression is determined by the left hand side. So your case sees `struct XTYPE*` and `struct YTYPE*`.

[6.5.16 Assignment operators - p3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16p3)

> An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by the
>   left operand. An assignment expression has the value of the left
>   operand after the assignment,111) but is not an lvalue. **The type of an
>   assignment expression is the type the left operand would have after
>   lvalue conversion.** The side effect of updating the stored value of the
>   left operand is sequenced after the value computations of the left and
>   right operands. The evaluations of the operands are unsequenced.

And the types of the operands for a conditional expression must satisfy this constraint:

[6.5.15 Conditional operator - p3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.15p3)

> One of the following shall hold for the second and third operands:
>
> - both operands have arithmetic type;
> - both operands have the same structure or union type;
> - both operands have void type;
> - both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;
> - one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant; or
> - one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void.

Since `struct XTYPE*` and `struct YTYPE*` are not pointers to compatible types (the only bullet which *may* even apply), and are in fact just pointers to unrelated types, your program is ill-formed.

---

<sub>A major point of contention here is that MSVC isn't a conforming C compiler (not C11 anyway). But the above rules haven't changed much since the last C version that MSVC *does* support, so there you have it.</sub>

Comment: I get it. Although my intention is that the result of either branch of the ternary expression will be tested for zero, the result of both branches must be the same type. By explicitly writing the test (second example), they have now become both boolean expressions and so are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Although you aren't using it, the compiler has to make a sensible type for the result of the tertiary operation by looking at the two RHS paths.
In the first case you gave it 2 unrelated pointer types X and Y, which it refuses to resolve directly to bool for the if statement. (bool doesn't exist as a specific type in C, so it would need to use some int type)

In the second case you have done this cast to bool, by comparing with 0/NULL/nullptr, though you have switched the logic from `if set` to `if clear`.

In c++ we have the concept of inheritance and related types, so the compiler can often find a common type to resolve these sorts of statements. In my experience different compilers have treated this situation differently, but with strict compliance settings it should always fail unless one of the operands is a subtype of the other.

One way I used to fix these issues in the old days was to use "double-pling" !! as a cast to boolean keeping the original sense:

```
 if (b ? !!(pX= (*pfFoo)())
       : !!(pY= (*pfFoo)()) )
 {
    ;
 }
```

The point of the double-pling is that it can be read as a single operation with a clear intent, while anything else has to be decoded by the reader.